Conditional deduplication in polars
I have a dataset i'm trying to remove duplicate entries from. The lazyframe i'm working with is structured like this:
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌──────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬───────┐
│ id   ┆ title      ┆ type             ┆ type2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---              ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ str        ┆ str              ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1001 ┆ Research A ┆ journal article  ┆ 35    │
│ 1002 ┆ Research B ┆ book chapter     ┆ 41    │
│ 1003 ┆ Research C ┆ journal article  ┆ 35    │
│ 1004 ┆ Research D ┆ conference paper ┆ 42    │
│ 1001 ┆ Research E ┆ journal article  ┆ 35    │
│ 1002 ┆ Research F ┆ journal article  ┆ 41    │
│ 1003 ┆ Research G ┆                  ┆ 41    │
│ 1002 ┆ Research I ┆ book chapter     ┆ 41    │
│ 1003 ┆ Research J ┆ journal article  ┆ 35    │
└──────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴───────┘
""")

I want to remove entries that have the same id, but there are actually different cases:

The duplicates have the same type (e.g. 1001): keep the first one.
The duplicates have a different type: discard the ones with an empty string ("") as type, and then keep only the entries that respect the following pairs of type and type2:

dict_df = pl.DataFrame({
    "type": ['journal article', 'book chapter', 'book chapter'],
    "type2": [35, 41, 42]
})

Expected output



id[i64]
title[str]
type[str]
type2[i64]




1001
Research A
journal article
35


1002
Research B
book chapter
41


1003
Research C
journal article
35


1004
Research D
conference paper
42




1001: same type, keep the first one
1002: different type, keep the first occurrence of the entries with pair {'book chapter': 41}
1003: different type, discard the entries with an empty type and keep the first occurrence
1004: not a duplicate

I've tried many things, mainly using the pl.when() expression, but I cannot work out a way to filter the groups.
(
    df
    .sort('type', descending=True)
    .group_by("id")
    .agg([
        pl.when(pl.col("type").n_unique() > 1)
        .then( ... )
        .otherwise(pl.all().first())
    ])
)



It helps if you post your data example as an actual DataFrame code snippet so would-be-answerers can test out their answers easily.

Also, in your original example there doesn't exist an item with id 1002 that has pair book chapter, 41.

Sort takes expressions and then unique has keep="first"


Create a preference table indicating how much you want each combination:

preference = pl.DataFrame({
    "type": ["journal article", "book chapter", "book chapter"],
    "iris_type": [35, 41, 42],
    "preference": [0, 1, 2]
})


Join the preference table with your data table:

joined = df.lazy().join(preference.lazy(), on=["type", "iris_type"], how="left")


Sort the joined table on the preference, pick the first one in each group and drop the preference column:

out = (
    joined.sort("preference", descending=True, nulls_last=True)
        .group_by("id")
        .first()
        .drop("preference")
        .collect()
)


hm, this doesn't work exactly as OP described, for example if type is unique per id, first row doesn't exists in dict but second does, or first row has empty type. But as it's an accepted answer I'd assume that this logic works for OP.

You could probably apply your logic in GroupBy context, but also you can first pre-filter the DataFrame so you only have the rows you want to keep:
(
    df
    .join(dict_df.with_row_index(), on=["type","type2"], how="left")
    .filter(
        (pl.col.type.n_unique().over("id") == 1) |
        ((pl.col.type != "") & (pl.col.index.is_not_null()))
    )
    .drop("index")
    .unique("id", keep="first", maintain_order=True)
    # alternatively,
    # .group_by("id").first()
)

┌──────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬───────┐
│ id   ┆ title      ┆ type             ┆ type2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---              ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ str        ┆ str              ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1001 ┆ Research A ┆ journal article  ┆ 35    │
│ 1003 ┆ Research C ┆ journal article  ┆ 35    │
│ 1004 ┆ Research D ┆ conference paper ┆ 42    │
│ 1002 ┆ Research F ┆ journal article  ┆ 35    │
└──────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴───────┘

